# Count unique records with conditional statement in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a table in Excel.

```
Id|Gender|Age|Test|Result|Center
1 |MALE  |11 | HB | 11   |Center1 
1 |MALE  |11 | UA |  8   |Center1
1 |MALE  |11 | BG | 100  |Center1
2 |FEMALE|12 | HB | 12   |Center1
2 |FEMALE|12 | UA | 10   |Center1
3 |MALE  |14 | HB | 14   |Center2
4 |FEMALE|13 | HB | 15   |Center2
```

I am able to find unique records but not getting how to put a conditional statement over it. Below is the queries I need.

Total males: 2

```
=SUMPRODUCT((report!D2:D232="MALE")/COUNTIF(report!B2:B232,report!B2:B232&""))
```

Total Females:2

```
=SUMPRODUCT((report!D2:D232="FEMALE")/COUNTIF(report!B2:B232,report!B2:B232&""))
```

I need the following queries.

```
Total Females with HB result above 14. ??


Total Females with HB result between 10 and 14 in Center1??
```

EDITS:- Every count should be from the unique counts from males and females.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Total Females with HB result above 14**

You can use `COUNTIFS` to specify multiple criteria in this case:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B232,"FEMALE", D2:D232,"HB", E2:E232, ">14")
```

This contains three checks:

- Does `B2:B232` = `FEMALE`?
- Does `D2:D232` = `HB`?
- Is `E2:E232` > 14?

In the case of your sample data, this outputs `1`.

**Total Females with HB result between 10 and 14 in Center1**

Again, use `COUNTIFS` with multiple parameters:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B232,"FEMALE", D2:D232,"HB", E2:E232, ">=10", E2:E232, "<=14", F2:F232, "Center1")
```

In this case, these are the checks:

- Does `B2:B232` = `FEMALE`?
- Does `D2:D232` = `HB`?
- Is `E2:E232` >= 10?
- Is `E2:E232` <= 14?
- Does `F2:F232` = `Center1`?

The output in the example data is again `1`.

Comment: Your formula does not account for the requirement to return a count of the **UNIQUE** records

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're correct in saying that, but the examples OP gave contained duplicates on the comparison fields so I had (incorrectly?) assumed that they were not looking to de-duplicate the results

Comment: From this statement "*I am able to find unique records but not getting how to put a conditional statement …*", I assumed he wanted a unique record count.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld And yet the examples that follow showing what the OP is looking for contain non-unique (duplicate) matches

Comment: I did not interpret his post that way.  He shows a unique count of females and males, but does not show what he expects for a result when he adds more criteria.  You may well be correct, but we'll have to wait for his response to see.

Comment: @Martin  - Thanks for the answer. Looks simple and clear. I mentioned in my question that I want to put a conditional statement over the unique records. Can you update your answer with unique records? It will be very helpful.

Comment: @Lucifer Did you look at the formula at the end of my answer?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Yes I used that formula but it is throwing error "That function is not valid". Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Format-as-table on the table and set a total row and set it to Count.

This way, as you filter on your conditions in each column, you will get a list with the subjects that fit the query as well as the total number of occurrence within the queried. This will however not find the unique Id's. See bootom of answer on how to do that with a matrix-formula

Result for query: Female with HB above 14:
[image: Result1]

Result for query: Female with HB between 10 and 14 in Center1:
[image: Result2]

To count unique ID's in the filtered table use this matrix-formula (apply with <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3; OFFSET(A2:A8; MATCH(ROW(A2:A8); ROW(A2:A8))-1; 0; 1));COUNTIF(A2:A8;"<"&A2:A8);"");COUNTIF(A2:A8;"<"&A2:A8))>0))
```

More info on this formula can be found here: https://www.get-digital-help.com/count-unique-distinct-values-in-a-filtered-table/

This would look like this:

[image: Result3]

Comment: How does that filter for the **Unique** subjects that meet the criteria?

Comment: By setting each condition as a filter in the corresponding column you can find the unique subjects that meet the criteria. Try it!

Comment: I tried that.  I selected `FEMALE`.  There are two Unique Females (Id 2; ID 4).  The Count line returns  `3`.

Comment: See my Google Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO3qTURz0m37jTEe9csOadIw608YGDKGx4-FUInRvOM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not helpful at all. Cannot apply filters to a View Only sheet.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have taken the question too litterary and I am looking for the amount of FEMALE values, not he amount of ID's that are FEMALE. See my Google Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO3qTURz0m37jTEe9csOadIw608YGDKGx4-FUInRvOM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for that insight @Ron Rosenfeld. I have edited my solution and included a matrix-funtion to count unique Id's within the filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the below:

**Formula:**

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=H3)*($B$2:$B$8=I3)*($C$2:$C$8=J3)*($D$2:$D$8=K3)*($E$2:$E$8=L3)*($F$2:$F$8=M3))`

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*For Office 365 Excel:*

If you want a

- Count of unique individuals meeting your criteria
- A method of easily changing the criteria

And assuming that

- `ID` identifies the individuals
- You have Excel 2016 with the new `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions

I suggest the following which will use the **Advanced Filter**

*You could also use a simple filter, but it may be a bit more difficult to set up the varying filter criteria, and they would not be visible in the results display**

- Turn your data range into a **Table** and name it `myTbl`
- Add a Helper column named `Visible`

  - Optionally you may HIDE this column
  - Formula for helper column: `=SUBTOTAL(3,[@ID])`

    - *This will return `0` if row is hidden, else `1`
- Use this formula for a **Unique Count**: `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(myTbl[ID],myTbl[Visible]=1),0,1)))`
- Set up a **Criteria Range** where you can type in the Criteria

  - See HELP for `Advanced Filter` for more information

Examples: (*I changed your data a bit to test for uniqueness*)

#### Base Data and empty Filter

[image]

#### Total Females with HB result between 10 and 14 in Center1

[image]

If you prefer not to use a filter, or a helper column, here is a formula to return this same last set of criteria:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTER(myTbl,(myTbl[Gender]="FEMALE")*(myTbl[Test]="HB")*(myTbl[Result]>=10)*(myTbl[Center]="Center1")),0,1)))
```

You can use this as an example as to how to create formulas to return a unique count of any other sets of criteria.

**EDIT:**

If you choose to use the Advanced Filter method with the `Visible` helper column, and if your ID's are all numeric, you can use this formula to obtain the Unique Count:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(myTbl[Visible],myTbl[Id]),IF(myTbl[Visible],myTbl[Id]))>0,1))
```

In versions of Excel that do not have dynamic array formulas, you must confirm the formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

Comment: I am getting error "That function is not valid". I think it is for Filter function.

Comment: @Lucifer That's too bad.  I guess you really need to have O365 for the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions.  And that Excel 2016 has not been updated for those functions.  I will update my description to show that.

Comment: I am using Microsoft office 365 Busines only but it does not have Filter function. Also, I googled and found that I need to join office insiders to get filter function.

Comment: @Lucifer I have O365 Home; I am **NOT**   an insider, and I got those functions a month or so ago.

Comment: If I shared the same sheet using the formula with the client. Might be possible HE will not have the updated 365. will it still work?? Is there any alternative of Filter function or answer to my question?? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @Lucifer Yes it would be possible, and if he doesn't have it, it won't work. There are alternative answers to your question, but it depends on how you will be inputting the variables for your filter. Simplest would be the Advanced Filter method with the helper column.  See my **EDIT** for a formula that will work in that situation.